# How can i use @ from mysql to java(jdbc)

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I can use @ in mysql. But I can't use @ in java(jdbc). Could you give some advice?

**mysql (working very well)**

```
select ssn from (select * from EMPLOYEE)EMPLOYEE_sorted,(select 
@pv='888665555') initialisation where find_in_set(superssn,@pv) and length(@pv 
:= concat(@pv,',',ssn));
```

**java (jdbc) doesn't work**

```
String query = "select ssn from (select * from EMPLOYEE)EMPLOYEE_sorted, 
(select @pv=888665555) initialisation where find_in_set(superssn,@pv) and length(@pv := concat(@pv,',',ssn))"
```

Answer (score 0):

To set this you may create a PreparedStatement and assign ‘?’ wherever you want to place the @xxxxxx.

To set the values inside the ‘?’ you have to use the command

```
setString()/setInt()/set<variable>();
```

This is more clear when I show you an example.

```
PreparedStatement p = con.prepareStatement("select * from people where 
(first_name = ? or last_name = ?) and address = ?");
p.setString(1, name);
p.setString(2, name);
p.setString(3, address);
```

Here is the [link](https://www.google.com.ar/amp/s/www.javaworld.com/article/2077706/core-java/named-parameters-for-preparedstatement.amp.html) to the sample.

Comment: sorry but i already used it
this is my part of the code



    'String query = "select ssn from (select * from 
    EMPLOYEE)EMPLOYEE_sorted,(select @pv=?) 
    initialisation where find_in_set(superssn,@pv) and 
    length(@pv := concat(@pv,',',ssn))";
    PreparedStatement p = conn.prepareStatement 
    (query);
     String ww =readEntry("Enter a ssn: ");
     p.setString(1,ww);
     ResultSet r = p.executeQuery();'